# How to reference foreign key to another foreign key in sequelize?

Tags: sql, database-design, orm, sequelize.js, relational-database

I have table 3 tables. Versions table has a reference to Project table via ProjectID. ***Then List table references ProjectID (which is a foriegn key) in the Versions table.***

List table has an "indirect" reference to Project table

```
Project Table 
---------------
ProjectID      


Versions Table 
---------------
VersionID
ProjectID (fk to project table) (UNIQUE constraint added)


List Table 
--------------
ListID
VersionID (fk to version table)
ProjectID (fk to fk in version table)
```

In sequilize  I have the the 3 models defined. And in List model here's how i am creating an association via:

```
// Create foreign keys
List.belongsTo(Versions, {
  onDelete: "cascade",
  foreignKey: "VersionID"
});

// Create foreign keys
ConsolidatedList.belongsTo(Versions, {
  onDelete: "cascade",
  foreignKey: "ProjectID"
});

*
```

> ***ISSUE**: For List model, sequilize on ProjectID field creates a reference to VersionID (pk) **instead** of ProjectID field(fk) in
>   Versions table!**

An exact query that is run by sequilize (see bolded):

Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `List` (`ID` INTEGER auto_increment , `ProjectID` INTEGER, `VersionID` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (`ID`), **FOREIGN KEY (`ProjectID`) REFERENCES `Versions` (`VersionID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE**, FOREIGN KEY (`VersionID`) REFERENCES `Versions` (`VersionID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: What is your 1 clear specific researched non-duplicate question? What is the problem? Where are you stuck? Where is your sequelize code? Please in code questions give a [mre]. Please do not ask duplicate questions. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS A FK references a PK or UNIQUE. It doesn't matter whether the referenced column list is a FK.

Comment: Your FK seems to be the composite FK (VersionID, ProjectID). A FK must reference a column list that is explicitly declared PK/UNIQUE. Do you have that? This is in any FK intro & your manual. It is a SO faq. Your post is not clear about exactly what each of your FKs, PKs & UNIQUE is.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Please describe exactly what you think you want to say by your declarations. Then exaclty what PK, UNIQUE & FK declarations you want to happen & what ones you think you're declaring. Because it's still not clear. In particular it's not clear if you want 2 FKs in List or one compound FK. Give a full cut & paste & runnable [mre] to reproduce. Have you researched compound/composite FKs? Do you understand my earlier commments? [Re composite/compound FKs.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29015156/3404097) PS A create table is not a query.

Comment: A belongsTo FK references the target table PK. ["By default the foreign key for a belongsTo relation will be generated from the target model name and the target primary key name." "In all cases the default foreign key can be overwritten with the foreignKey option."](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/associations/) And that is what you are getting. Why do you think it would create a FK to a field with the same name? See the documentation. "In cases where as has been defined it will be used in place of the target model name." PS This is besides your compound/composite FK issutes.

Comment: What relationships do these foreign keys represent?

Comment: @WalterMitty Each project has a version and each project's version has a list (of data)

Comment: What is a list?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define Sequelize associations as mentioned below -

```
List.belongsTo(Versions, {
  onDelete: "cascade",
  foreignKey: "VersionID",
  targetKey: "VersionID"
});

List.belongsTo(Versions, {
  onDelete: "cascade",
  foreignKey: "ProjectID",
  targetKey: "ProjectID"
});
```

I hope it helps!